# Cant send Facebook Publish_actions permission to review

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-c#-sdk

In an Unity Game, i use the facebook scores api, so i need the publish_actions permission (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/scores).

Despite of i tested my functionality and made requests with test users and real users, when i go to submit to review the app in order to get approved the permission, i have an issue, "it looks like you haven't made any API requests to publish content with the publish_actions permission...", so i can't submit to review de app on facebook.

Somebody have any idea? i only use publish_actions for score managements.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> it looks like you haven't made any API requests to publish content with the publish_actions permission...

They telling you did not made any API call with that permission. But by telling your steps seems you did API call, so Just try again. Make sure you are passing the publish_action while requesting access token.